# How to display song chords in FLUTTER

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have one requirement to display the songs chords. Like in this example https://songbase.life/admin/example . Actually this built in react js but i want to implement same in Flutter

I have tried Using Stack and TextSpan, but not getting exact positions.

Here is my code, that I have tried...

```
List<Widget> _lyrics() {
final lines = lyrics.split('\\n');
List<String> newLines = [];
print('Start parsing');
int cachedindex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  final newIndex = int.tryParse(lines[i]) ?? 0;
  if (cachedindex == 0) {
    newLines.add(lines[i]);
  } else {
    final lastIndex = newLines.length - 1;
    final lastData = '${newLines[lastIndex]} ${lines[i]}';
    newLines[lastIndex] = lastData;
  }
  cachedindex = newIndex;
}
print('end parsing');
return newLines.map((line) => _lyricsLine(_processedLyrics(line))).toList();
}

 LyricsLineModal _processedLyrics(String line) {
 return LyricsLineModal(lyrics: line, chords: '');
}

Iterable<String> _allStringMatches(String text, RegExp regExp) =>
  regExp.allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0));

Widget _lyricsLine(LyricsLineModal line) {
//To check if starts with integer
//print(line.lyrics.startsWith(new RegExp('[0-9]')));
String lineNumber = '';
if (line.lyrics.startsWith(new RegExp('[0-9]'))) {
  List<String> lineArr = line.lyrics.split(' ');
  lineNumber = '${lineArr[0]}.';
  lineArr.removeAt(0);
  line.lyrics = lineArr.join(' ');
}

var regExp = RegExp('\[[A-Z0-9a-z]+\]');
var aa = _allStringMatches(line.lyrics, regExp).toList();
//print('this.........');
//print(aa);
String newStr = line.lyrics;
String chords = '';
//List<int> positions = [];
int previousIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
  //positions.add(newStr.indexOf(aa[i].toString()));
  final int index = newStr.indexOf(aa[i].toString());
  chords = chords + (' ' * (index - previousIndex)) + aa[i].toString();
  //newStr = newStr.replaceAll(aa[i].toString(), '');
  previousIndex = index;
}
final bool haveChords = chords.trim().length != 0;
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
  child: Stack(
    //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      //_chords(haveChords, chords),
      _chords(haveChords, newStr),
      _line(haveChords, newStr, lineNumber),
    ],
  ),
  );
}

Widget _line(bool haveChords, String line, String lineNumber) {
EdgeInsets padding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0);
double lineSpacing = 1.2;
if (haveChords) {
  padding = EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 18, 0, 0);
  lineSpacing = 2.4;
}
return Container(
  padding: padding,
  //color: Colors.blue,
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      _lineNumber(lineNumber, lineSpacing),
      Space(horizontal: 5),
      Expanded(child: _lineText(line, lineSpacing)),
    ],
  ),
);
}

Widget _lineNumber(String lineNumber, double lineSpacing) {
return Container(
  width: 24,
  child: Text(
    lineNumber,
    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: Constants.FONT_FAMILY_FUTURA,
      fontSize: 16,
      height: lineSpacing,
    ),
  ),
);
}

Widget _lineText(String line, double lineSpacing) {
List<String> arrLine = line.split('');
bool textReturn = true;
List<String> arrLineNew = arrLine.map((e) {
  if (e == '[') {
    textReturn = false;
  }
  String returnText = textReturn ? e : '';
  if (e == ']') {
    textReturn = true;
  }
  return returnText;
}).toList();
String theLine = arrLineNew.join('');
return Text(
  //line,
  theLine,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: Constants.FONT_FAMILY_FUTURA,
    fontSize: 16,
    height: lineSpacing,
  ),
);
}

Widget _chords(bool haveChords, String chords) {
if (!haveChords) {
  return Container();
}
return Row(
  children: [
    Space(horizontal: 29),
    Expanded(child: _chordText(chords)),
  ],
);
}

Widget _chordText(String chords) {
final List<String> arrChords = chords.split('');
Color colour = Colors.transparent; //.transparent;
//Color colour2 = Colors.black; //.transparent;
//List<TextSpan> spans2 = [];
//
final List<TextSpan> spans = arrChords.map((e) {
  if (e == ']') {
    colour = Colors.transparent; //transparent;
  }
  var textSpan = _chordTextSpan(e, colour);
  //spans2.add(_chordTextSpan(e, colour2.withOpacity(0.6)));
  if (e == '[') {
    colour = Color(0xff222211);
  }
  return textSpan;
 }).toList();

 return Stack(
  children: [
    RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '',
        children: spans,
      ),
    )
  ],
);
}

TextSpan _chordTextSpan(String text, Color colour) {
return TextSpan(
  text: text,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: Constants.FONT_FAMILY_FUTURA,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    height: 2.4,
    color: colour,
  ),
 );
}

Widget _chordText2(String chords) {
final List<String> arrChords = chords.split('');
Color colour = Colors.red; //.transparent;
final List<TextSpan> spans = arrChords.map((e) {
  if (e == ']') {
    colour = Colors.red; //transparent;
  }
  var textSpan = _chordTextSpan2(e, colour);
  if (e == '[') {
    colour = Color(0xff222211);
  }
  return textSpan;
}).toList();
return RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: '',
    children: spans,
  ),
);
}

TextSpan _chordTextSpan2(String text, Color colour) {
return TextSpan(
  text: text,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: Constants.FONT_FAMILY_FUTURA,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    height: 2.4,
    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
  ),
);
}
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE0LT.png)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this?

Comment: Hi, Not yet. I am still facing the issue. It is not aligning properly.

Comment: I tried to use https://github.com/paurakhsharma/flutter_chord it is also give me overflow issue if line is longer than screen width. I am trying to solved the issue. If you can handle the line with, it is working perfect.